Помогите выполнить код js последовательно
Запрашиваю и формирую массив данных из БД, на выходе должен получиться массив объектов
const namingArr = req.body; //получаю массив запросов
 let matArr = [];
   namingArr.forEach((item, index, array) => {
     let naming = item;
          Material.findByNaming(naming, (err, materials) => { //получаю значения из БД
          if (err) return next (err)
            matArr.push(materials) // добавляю значения в массив
        });
      });
          
      console.log(matArr); 

а далее возникает проблема, данные попадают в массив значений позже, чем выполняется console.log(matArr);
Помогите переписать, чтобы код работал как синхронный?
